# EditText show text with hint

Tags: android

Is it possible to show text + `hint` or grayed text, I can use `SpannableStringBuilder` but the `hint` or grayed text should be ignored by the selection and keyboard.

Example in picture, the hint not disappear until the phone number is fully entered.

[image]